# Access to AVAudioRecorder's meterEnabled give error

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to `ON` meter with AVAudioRecorder, but it give error as

```
Cann't assign to the result of expression
```

Declaration:

```
var recorder : AVAudioRecorder?
..
```

Definition

```
self.recorder?.meteringEnabled = true // Error here
```

Comment: Hi, Did you able to record audio using Swift? If so could you please share the full example?

Answer (score 1):

You need to unwrap the `self.recorder` variable like so:

```
self.recorder!.meteringEnabled = true
```

Comment: This also resolve my problem. but above answer is correct way to set optional value. +1 for you..

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining does not support the setting of property values. It is only used for querying (see: getting) properties, and calling methods.

So code should be

```
if let recorder = self.recorder?{
     recorder.meteringEnabled = true
}
```

This will only set the properties on the object if it has a value. Since your ivar is most likely defined as `var player: AVAudioPlayer?`, the compiler doesn't actually know whether it will have a value.

As mentioned in the language guide, under the [Calling Properties Through Optional Chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/OptionalChaining.html) section:

> > You cannot, however, set a property’s value through optional chaining.